# How request with n-n association rails 4.0

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 entities : Fighter, Status, its an n <-> n association.

So I have an other table "fighter_status".

How can I write in rails 4.0 the sql for: "I want all fighter where **don't have** the Status X" (where X is an status_id)?

I have find :

```
"Fighter.all.where("id NOT IN (SELECT fighter_id FROM fighter_statuses WHERE fighter_statuses.fighter_id = fighters.id AND status_id = #{X})")
```

but exist a better way?

thx.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Rails 4 so you can go for `where.not` as below:

```
Fighter.joins(:statuses).where.not('fighter_statuses.status_id = ?', X)
```

Comment: It's the first way I tried, but it's used "INNER JOIN", so return no result, if we use join method, we have to use LEFT JOIN, so how can i transform inner join to left join?